# Alternate downloads of 64bit ESX VMWare Infrastructure Client?

Tags: vmware-esx, 64-bit

We've got an ESX 3.5 server that is currently unpatched, still running release code.

While we plan to update to current one weekend over the next few weeks, I'd like to get the VI Client installed on my 64bit Vista workstation.  Unfortunately, 64bit clients are only included in newer patch updates.  Is there anywhere I can get the 64bit VI Client to use to connect to my server?  I can't find it online anywhere, normally you just download it from your own server as the patches contain the client updates.  Also, will the newer client only properly connect to a similarly patched ESX server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly there is no 64-bit specific VI Client, I'm really not sure it would benefit in any way from being so either. What I do know is that the VI Client that cames with 3.5U3 and later runs just fine on 64-bit Windows boxes. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not looking for any performance benefits, but the 3.5(unpatched) client won't even install on a 64bit OS.  I can't get my hands on the U3 client, and am looking for a source to download.

Comment: It's in a directory on the VC 2.5U4/5 disk/.ISO file - the one you're going to install in the next few weeks.

Comment: Thanks again, that did it!  I kept looking in the ESK Update ISO's an dhadn't looked in the virtualcenter update ISO.  I've got the uypdated client installed and running on my 64bit PC.  Cheers.

Comment: I was so excited , my typing suffered, but thanks again.